Npgsql - Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program
I have a simple API developed with .NET 8, which connects to a postgreSQL DB using Npgsql version 4.0.0 .
The API opens the connection, queries the database version, and closes the connection.
the API was uploaded to 2 servers, running Windows Server 2019 and exposing the API via IIS.
Both servers have:

the same version of IIS
same IIS configuration
same deployment path
same API build loaded
same .NET Core hosting bundle

The API build has:

same web.config
same path
same library
same build

But, while on one server everything works correctly, the other generates this error during the connection.open();
 Values Problem to open the connection
  System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.Read(Boolean async)
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.Read()
     at Npgsql.PostgresDatabaseInfo.LoadBackendTypes(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async)
     at Npgsql.PostgresDatabaseInfo.LoadPostgresInfo(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async)
     at Npgsql.PostgresDatabaseInfoFactory.Load(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async)
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlDatabaseInfo.Load(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async)
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.LoadDatabaseInfo(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async)
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
     at MyAPI.Values.Values(String httpRequestDomainName) in \Controllers\Values.cs:line 45

I tried to change:

both framework-dependent and self-contained builds,
web.config
reset the IIS
Cleanup of IIS temporary files
reset the pool
Update the NPGSQL library to version 8.0.4

but without success.
The strange thing is that when using Kestrel the application works correctly, only when using IIS it doesn't work.
For business choice it is not possible to use kestrel and we must use IIS.
thanks

Since this API is already working fine in one of your IIS servers, I think there should be some differences between the two server environments or configurations.
First, you can check whether the operating system and security update versions are consistent between these two servers.
Second, compare the .NET SDK versions installed on both servers to see if they are the same, since the publish step is handled by the .NET Core SDK. Just execute this command line: dotnet --list-sdks.
Third, make sure that the managed app pool is configured with No Managed Code and Integrated Mode.
If none of the above works, I think you'll have to look for more information to pinpoint the problem, such as more detailed log information.

In the server there are only the .Net hosting bundle and there is no sdk. I configured pool with No Managed Code and Integrated Mode, however, without success.
On the server where the API software as-is not working with IIS, the API software works with:

kestrel;
older versione of Npgsql (2.2.7);

with version 4.0.0 and IIS nothing works

It's strange that the same environment produces different results. I think you need detailed log information to try to locate the problem.
